# Trying to filter an array of objects with another array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, shopping-cart

I am trying to add a shopping cart to my application. I need to filter my **product array** by matching the **ID** with an object within my **cart array** and then display it on my Flatlist.
I have tested to make sure I can filter the products list using other methods like includes().

I cannot get the current code to work.

I have simplified my code to the very minimum for readability.

```
    <View>
        <Text>
            Cart
        </Text>
        <FlatList
            data={this.props.products.products.filter(product => this.props.cart.cart.some(el => el === product.id))}
            renderItem={renderMenuItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        />
    </View>
```

This is my db.json file holding the arrays.

```
"products": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "chargers",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 0,
            "price": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "ezy",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 50,
            "price": 40
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "ezy",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 100,
            "price": 70
        }
],
    "cart": [
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ]
```

**The result is currently an empty Flatlist.**
Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Comment: whats your this.props.cart look like?

Comment: If your cart item is an object I think you're missing the object attribute, for example el.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the 'id' property of your cart array item inside your 'some()' method.

For example:
`this.props.cart.cart.some(el => el.id === product.id))`

So the full code would be

`data={this.props.products.products.filter(product => this.props.cart.cart.some(el => el.id === product.id))}`

This is because your `cart` is an array of objects with `id` as the property, so in your code the `el` is referencing the cart object, and equality is checked with the `el.id`.

I tried to break it down so it's runnable as a JS snippet so you can see it below in action.

```js
const products = [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "chargers",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 0,
            "price": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "ezy",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 50,
            "price": 40
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Ezywhip Pro",
            "category": "ezy",
            "label": "",
            "featured": false,
            "description": "Ezywhip Pro Cream Chargers, Made by MOSA",
            "image": "images/ezywhip.png",
            "quantity": 100,
            "price": 70
        }
]

const cart = [
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ]
const filtered = products.filter(product => cart.some(el => el.id === product.id))
console.log('Filtered: ', filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i am understanding, you want to display a list of cart and its corresponding products. So you can iterate the **cart array** to get the id then filter **product array** to get matching products.

```js
    <View>
            <Text>
                Cart
            </Text>
            { 
                this.props.carts.forEach(cart => 
                    (<FlatList
                        data={this.props.products.filter(product => product.id === cart.id)}
                        key={cart.id}/>)
                );
            }
        </View>
```

Some suggestions:

- "cart" key in db.json should be "carts" if it's an array.
- you should have another field like "cartId" in product object

Comment: Thank you I made adjustments using your suggestions. Although, using your solution gave me the error 'undefined is not a function (near '...this.props.carts.forEach...')